# page-header bootstrap with dotted line

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the component **Page header** , that creates a border-`bottom: 1px solid #eee;` I want change this border to be dotted is a bootstrap class for this? or I need do it manually?

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Example page header <small>Subtext for header</small></h1>
</div>
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can override the styling of it. This only works if your stylesheet is loaded after the bootstrap stylesheet.

If this is the case just do:

```
.page-header {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #eee;
}
```

Comment: thanks I know I can override, I was looking for a bootstrap solution for this, but looks like is not possible.

Comment: not really sure what kind of 'bootstrap-solution' you would like. different classnames for every type of border? (which is basicly the same as this solution).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add some CSS.

```
.page-header {
   border-bottom: 1px dotted #eee;
}
```

Comment: thanks I know I can override, I was looking for a bootstrap solution for this, but looks like is not possible.